# How do I find the browser scroll bars total scrollable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scrollbar

So I know that $(window).scrollTop() will give me the current position of the browser scroll bar, but how do I find the total scrollable area?

i.e. If I scroll all the way down the final  $(window).scrollTop() might equal 300px and scrolling back to the top would return it back to 0px, but suppose I wanted to find the total $(window).scrollTop() area before hand? How would I do that?

i.e. If I use $(window).scrollTop() I want something to happen when it get's to a certain point.

So pretty much is there a way to find out that $(window).scrollTop() total is 300px before hand? If the browser height is changed/resized then the $(window).scrollTop() will change, so I I'll need to find out what the new $(window).scrollTop() total is once the browser is resized.

Thanks.

Comment: So for whatever reason when I try and use $(window).height(); and change the browser height, what's in the console log is the same. It never changes even though I changed the browser height. I've tried this in other browsers and it works fine, but not for my project. Anyone see this issue before? I'm using bootstrap it that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this to get the maximum scrolleable value:

```
$(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

You get the entire web height and substract the window height (the height that you can see on your window), so the rest of it is what is left to scroll

Comment: I tried this and it returned 0 for me because they both return the same result. The thing is when you change the height of the browser then the $(window).scrollTop(); total changes. So for example if you have your browser in full screen vs having it shrunk down the $(window).scrollTop() total number changes. scrolling all the way to the bottom with browser maximized can be 90px vs 500px if the browser height is changed by the user.

Comment: So you have to use this "math" every time you change the window size.. If you say that both values are the same, then you have nothing to scroll on your page, because the view equals the page, so it fits entirely on your view. Do you follow me? Maybe you should post your code so I can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for the help Pablo. I figured it out. It was the stupidest think ever. I forgot to add in <!doctype html> it caused the issue. Thanks for the help.